# How to create an apk in gideros

Tags: android, mobile, lua, apk, gideros

I want to create an apk for my android device.

How I'm going to do this ?

I could not find anything about this.

I tried file/ export project,
but I did not set android sdk directory, java directory,vs..

Do I have to set these properties?

Answer (score 1):

http://giderosmobile.com/DevCenter/index.php/Installing_Gideros_Studio

Did you install it properly? (I'm not aware of any Android .apk build process working without core Android SDK from Google, all the alternative builders use the chain tool from the original SDK, gideros looks to be the same case).

After installation, here are some Android deployment instructions:
http://giderosmobile.com/DevCenter/index.php/Deployment#Android_deployment

Comment: yes it's installed properly. I tried this my friends computers same way. We are trying to learn gideros. So we need to create an apk for test our projects.

Comment: @Yiğit if you did follow that installation guide, then follow here: http://giderosmobile.com/DevCenter/index.php/Deployment#Android_deployment  (I'm not gideros user, so don't expect me to help you, those guides should contain everything you need).

Comment: I know this site my friend. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Yiğit The second link toward the end contain the answer to your question. In Gideros studio do the export, import it in Eclipse, run or build apk. *"I tried file/ export project"* ... and the result was? Were files created? Was it possible to import it to Eclipse? If not, any error messages? Etc.. your original question is too broad, not specifying the actual problem you have.